# What does it mean for a pointer to point to a location just immediately past the end of an object?

Tags: c++, pointers

What does it mean for a pointer to point to a location just immediately past the end of an object?

From C++ Primer, pg 52:

> Pointer Value
>
> The value (i.e., the address) stored in a pointer can be in one of four states:
>
> 1. It can point to an object.
> 2. **It can point to the location just immediately past the end of an object.**
> 3. It can be a null pointer, indicating that it is not bound to any object.
> 4. It can be invalid; values other than the preceding three are invalid.

Comment: It means that if you decrement it, it points to the last object in an array. (A single object is considered like an array with one element.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Past the end of an object" becomes more interesting in the context of arrays.

Suppose you have a two element array: 
`int arr[2] = {1, 2}`

Based on `arr` you can compute these pointers:

`int * p1 = arr
int * p2 = arr + 1
int * p3 = arr + 2`

You can dereference `p1` and `p2`, but attempting to do the same to `p3` invokes undefined behavior.
Also, any pointer arithmetic based on `arr` that results in another pointer than the three mentioned above means UB.

So, the only things you can do with `p3` are:

- subtracting values (leading to either the values of `p1` or `p2`)
- compare it with another pointer (`if p3 == arr + 2`)

As for reasons why it should be considered valid, consider an usual way to use iterators:

`for (container::iterator iter = myContainer.start(); iter != myContainer.end(); ++iter)`

Here, `myContainer.end()` might be just a pointer to an element just past the end (of an array). It would be a shame if it wasn't a valid pointer and the whole construct were UB.

Answer (score 3):

A pointer immediately past the end of an object is a pointer whose address is offset from that of the object by exactly `sizeof object`.

Since pointer arithmetic already considers the type of the object:

```
T object;
T *past = &object + 1; // 1 is sizeof object
```

Or doing manual arithmetic:

```
T object;
char *past = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&object) + sizeof object;
```

Although in the second case, due to the difference in types it would be trickier to use the pointer correctly.